Geometry problem with external tangent of two circles
Let's consider two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$.
We note their intersections $A$ and $B$. Then we draw a circle $C_3$ which is tangent interiorly with $C_1$ and $C_2$.
Now we note $X$ the common point of $C_1$ and $C_3$ and $Y$ the common point of $C_2$ and $C_3$.
Now we place $Z$ the intersection of $[AB]$ and $C_3$ that is closer to $A$.
Finaly, we draw $P$ the other intersection of $XZ$ and $C_1$ and $Q$ the intersection of $YZ$ and $C_2$
How do we show that the place of $P$ and $Q$ is still the same for every choice of $C_3$ ?
I see that $PQ$ is the common tangent of $C_1$ and $C_2$ and therefore is independant of the choice of $C_3$. But could you help me proving that $PQ$ is the external tangent ?


Choices for $C_3$? Is there any other way where $C_3$ can be drawn other than the one given?

No there is many way to chose $C_3$, you juste have to chose a circle that is tangent to both $C_1$ and $C_2$ and there is an infinity of such circles

Woww. Like any 2 points on the circle, and any other random point in the plane? But internally only one such possible circle right? @mattandmaths

@Gwen you can reduce C3 radius and you can "bump it up" against the space inside the intersection to get another one.

Let us use inversion to show the following lemma, equivalent to the given problem:

Lemma: Consider two circles $\odot(O)$, $\odot(O')$, intersecting in two points, $A,B$, and having $PQ$ as common tangent, $P\in\odot(O)$, $Q\in\odot(O')$, let $Z$ be a point of the segment $AB$, and

intersect $PZ$ with $\odot(O)$, obtaining a second point $X\ne P$ on $\odot(O)$, and
intersect $QZ$ with $\odot(O')$, obtaining a second point $Y\ne Q$ on $\odot(O')$.

Then the circle $\odot(XYZ)$ is tangent to both circles $\odot(O)$, and $\odot(O')$.


Proof: Consider the inversion $*$ ("star") in $Z$ with power $K$, which is the common power of $Z$ w.r.t. the two given circles ($Z$ is on the radical axis of them)
$$
K 
= ZA\cdot ZB
= ZP\cdot ZX
= ZQ\cdot ZY\ .
$$
So the pairs of points $(A,B)$, $(P,X)$, $(Q,Y)$ correspond w.r.t. this inversion. The pink circle $(PAX)$ is mapped on itself (as a set),
$(PAX)^*=(P^*A^*B^*)=(XBP)$. The blue circle $(ZXY)$ is mapped to a line (since it passes through the center of inversion $Z$), which is $X^*Y^*=PQ$. The two geometrical figures we started with (pink and blue circle intersecting in $X$) are transformed in two geometrical figures (same pink circle and blue line) which are tangent (in $X^*=P$). So the initial figures are also tangent.
Same arguments works for brown and blue instead of pink and blue.
$\square$

Let O and W be the centers of $C_3$ and $C_2$, respectively. Notice that Y, O, W are collinear by the property of tangent circles. We'll mark $∠OZX = ∠OXZ = \alpha$ and $∠OZY = ∠OYZ = \beta$. ($OZ = OX = OY$ as radiuses, and because of that $\Delta ZOX, \Delta ZOY, \Delta XOY$ are isosceles.) Then, $∠XOY = 2∠XZY = 2 \alpha + 2 \beta; ∠OXY = ∠OYX = \frac{180° - 2 \alpha - 2 \beta}{2} = 90° - \alpha - \beta$.
$∠YXP = ∠YXO + ∠OXZ = 90° - \alpha - \beta + \alpha = 90° - \beta$
By the intersecting chords theorem, $QZ * ZY = AZ * ZB$, and also $PZ * ZX = AZ * ZB$. This means that $QZ * ZY = PZ * ZX$, which implies that PYXQ is cyclic, or that $∠YXP = ∠YQP = 90° - \beta$.
(I will explain, why is this so, because I don't know, do I need to. $QZ * ZY = PZ * ZX <=> \frac{ZY}{PZ} = \frac{ZX}{QZ}, ∠PZQ = ∠YZX$, and because of the SAS theorem of congruency, $\Delta PZQ$ and $\Delta YZX$ are congruent, which means that $∠YXP = ∠YQP = 90° - \beta$.)
$∠ZYO = ∠YQW = \beta$, because $\Delta QWY$ is isosceles. $∠PQW = ∠PQY + ∠YQW = 90° - \beta + \beta = 90°$.
This means that PQ is perpendicular to a radius of $C_2$, and because of this it is tangent to it. The same way you can prove that it is tangent to $C_1$.

